# c# WPF Pieces ProgressBar Bittorrent alike

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, progress-bar, chunks

I have a table in a database with phone numbers with a boolean value (true or false).

[image: Table]

In my program, I make a query to get a range of numbers (from 34600000000 to 34600500000) there are missing numbers so from this 500.000 query, I might get 5000 phones. But this might grow and I could have querys with 100.000+ numbers.

I want that when I do the query, I want to have a progressbar displaying a green value for the numbers that are true, a red value for the ones that are false, and a grey value for the missing numbers. Just like in BitTorrent.

[image: BitTorrent pieces progressBar]

I´m asking for help because I can´t find anything at all regarding this type of Pieces ProgressBar, I´m not even sure I name it the right way.

Comment: Just create a regular progress bar and template it to draw an image instead. The image source will have to be generated in code, see [Fast Pixel Operations in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617613/Fast-Pixel-Operations-in-NET-With-and-Without-unsa) for details.

Comment: Hm wow @MarkFeldman I never thought of such an approach. I´m going to learn about this approach and I will post what I come up with. Thank you!